# Is this eye-bleeding theme in Visual Studio Code normal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I installed Visual Studio Code for the first time today and was greeted with eye-bleeding dark blue on very dark gray. which is impossible to see. Is this normal or is there a style in my environment that's overriding it?

[image]

Comment: Use `File > Preferences > Color Theme` and choose a theme that you like, or search the Market place for lots of other alternatives `One Dark Pro` is a nice dark theme

Comment: You might want to create a bug report at the [VS Code issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode).